# Python pattern design implementation

Tags: python, design-patterns

So, I have some student class that calculate grades with 40% from exams and 60%. And need to use some design pattern that allows me to use different calculate to calculate with ratio 45% and 55% without changing student class. And in main I have to print score with using calculate 1, then other calculate 2, and then back to calculate one. I believe it might be either Factory Pattern, or adapter pattern but I do not know how to implement them.

```
class Student(Calculate):
    def __init__(self, studentName):
        self.__studentName = studentName
        self.__homeworks = []
        self.__exams = []


    def calculate(self):
        ... variant #1

def main():
    ...

    print('calculate 1')
    print('===========')
    student1.calculate()
    ... variant #1

    print('calculate 2')
    print('===========')
    ???
    ... variant #2

    print()
    print('calculate 1')
    print('===========')

    ... variant #1

 


main()
```

I need to somehow to be able put this calculate on calculate 2, and switch back

```
def calculate(self):
        ... variant #2
```

Comment: Could you shorten your example to be [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Did you consider just providing the information about the test weighting to the constructor, storing it as part of the instance, and using it as part of the calculation? I have no idea what use "design patterns" are supposed to be here. Smells like over-engineering. Like, I really, sincerely believe you will find this problem a hundred times easier if you imagine that you had never heard of such a thing as a "design pattern", and simply think about how to solve the problem.